# align the fixed position image on center for all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed header and a image below the header.

The image has a property `position: fixed`.

Now for some devices the image is not in the center as It should be.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cxumhp9k/) the fiddle for it.

The left side has more spaces than the right hand side.

Also above the image, I want to add a `p` tag which is not showing up for some reason.

Please let me know what's wrong here.

```
 <div class="content-wrapper new-class">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                     <div class="center-logo description">
                          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ECTLTbK.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                           <P class="step1description"  See price</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this solution:

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333230;
}
.content-wrapper .center-logo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 125px;
    left:0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0 15px;
    z-index: 1001;
    background-color: #333230;
}
.content-wrapper .center-logo img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center-logo p.step1description  {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.description {
    margin:30px 0 30px 0 !important;
}
.content-wrapper .content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.new-class{
     padding-bottom: 134px;
     top: 134px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="content-wrapper new-class">
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                 <div class="center-logo description">
                     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ECTLTbK.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                     <p class="step1description">  See price</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

You have some typos on html and css! - Here you can find a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/cxumhp9k/1/

Comment: which typos?

Got it working with 1st answer. Let me check this

Comment: `<P class="step1description"  See price</p>` not valid! And on css `.center-logo .step1description p` - i think it should be `.center-logo p.step1description`?

Comment: oops, yeah. Get it now. Thanks @seb

Answer (score 1):

Add `left:0` on `.content-wrapper .center-logo`

```
.content-wrapper .center-logo { left:0;}
```

Comment: oops, I think this should do. I was givng `left:0px` to the image of the above mentioned class.

Comment: are you able to get the written text under class `step1description`??